# Need some help with decryption

Tags: decryption

I've used x64dbg to work out decryption in a particular program. I've found where it changes the encrypted material into readable text but can't work out the best way to use this information to convert multiple files.

Is it a standardized encryption method? (eg. blowfish/aes) 
[image: Assembler]

It basically copies the file to memory then cycles through this (and one other cycle above it).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to ask this on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: What is stopping you from writing a program that just does all of what you see for you?

Comment: Thanks camp0 will do.  I could do that MechMK1. Just have to covert to c# or learn some more assembly :-)